# Two Finger Scrolling not detected on an Inspirion 2-in-1 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, brightness, xinput

I would like to be able to use the twofinger scrolling on my touchpad, but xinput is not detecting this method, but only the on-button method, which instead I don't have. In the following you can see the section regarding the scroll methods of the output of the command `xinput --list-props 13`,

```
Device 'PS/2 Generic Mouse':
Device Enabled (115):   1
libinput Scroll Methods Available (258):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (259):   0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (260):   0, 0, 1
```

I also tried with synclient, which is instead always replying with

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

Reading here and there I understood that it might be a kernel issue. Is that possible? Should I try with a fresh installation of Ubuntu? I installed Ubuntu 20.04.
My computer is a Dell Inspirion 5000 2-in-1, and for instance the touchpad on the screen is perfectly working, while I don't have any control on its brightness (the F6 and F7 are not working and there is no settings where I can set the brightness).

Comment: You do not need a whole fresh install of Ubuntu to change the kernel. Search the site and get the steps to update or change your kernel version. Afresh install of same Ubuntu software gives you the same kernel

Comment: So you think that this is actually a kernel problem and this should help?

Comment: No idea just saying it does not take a fresh install, the kernel can be upgraded separate. A fresh install of the same version will most likely give you the same kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve everything by updating Ubuntu to the 20.10, and with that also the kernel from 5.4 to 5.8!